# Display in table format from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, automation

I have table with `product_category` and its has more than 20 categories and I want to display them in table format like below image

[image]

I like to place categories in 5 `td` then how I can be fixed towards `tr` in a `table`

Below is code I have tried, but its not giving the desired output

And below is the image that might be solution I needed

[image]

Below code

```
<table>
<?php

$fquery5 = mysql_query("select Cat_ID, Cat_Name from product_category where Active_Flag=1");    

    $count1 = mysql_num_rows($fquery5);

    $hor_length = 5;
    $ver_length = $count1 / $hor_length;

    $data1 = mysql_fetch_row($fquery5);

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $ver_length; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";
            for ($j = $i + $hor_length; $j <= $count1; $j++) {
                    echo "<td>";
                        echo "Id : " . $data1[0] . " = " . $data1[1];
                    echo "</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    } 

?>
</table>
```

Added resultant output image answered by `@DaveRandom`

[image]

Comment: Should the items be sorted alfabetacally from top to bottom like in the example?

Comment: no radomly or from as it is from database.. I will try out both solutions

Comment: @Leven You'd just add an `ORDER BY` to the SQL query in order to do that, anyway...

Comment: @DaveRandom i know about getting it from `order by` other `asc` and `desc` but its not working out what we wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (**FIXED**):

```
<?php

  // Number of columns
  $hor_length = 5;

  // Do the query, get the number of rows in the result
  $fquery5 = mysql_query("
    SELECT Cat_ID, Cat_Name
    FROM product_category
    WHERE Active_Flag = 1
  ");    
  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($fquery5);

  // Start of table
  echo "<table>\n<tr>\n";

  // Loop the results with a counter
  for ($i = 1; $row = mysql_fetch_row($fquery5); $i++) {
    // Every iteration echos a cell
    echo "<td>Id : " . $row[0] . " = " . $row[1] . "</td>\n";
    // If we're at the end of a row, echo a row break, unless it is the last result
    if (!($i % $hor_length) && $i < $numrows) {
      echo "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
    }
  }

  // Right-pad the end row with empty cells
  for ($i--; $i % $hor_length; $i++) {
    echo "<td></td>\n";
  }

  // Echo the end of the table
  echo "</tr>\n</table>";
```

See a [working example](http://codepad.org/Z3sX94VM) (manually created the data array since I can't query a DB from codepad)

Comment: its giving an error `Undefined variable: numrows in` and its displayed the same first `product_category` 15 times in same `tr`

Comment: I have just made a couple of corrections, try current version

Comment: Yes we got it but, first `product_category` adjacent listing is leaving out or starting form next `tr` and i have added that image in question

Comment: I like the comments for this solution is more important to understant,.. Thanks for solution and comments